Awk /Sed or TCL script to search series of patterns
I am having one File as stated below
File 1
Module1 (a dd ddd )
jdjd ikdnd kdndn didkdn;
jdjdjl kdkdk kdkd lkd;
Ann {"Load DR"}  ;
V { REST_TMS=1 ;
      REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
}
V {   REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI2 = 0;
     REST_TMS=0;
}
V { REST_TMS=0 ;
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;

}
V { 
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
     REST_TMS=1;
}
jjd djdjdj djdj (ndhdn )
jdjdjd jdjd jdjd 
Ann( " Load IR"}
Ann ("Load DR 2"}
V { REST_TMS=1 ;
      REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
}
V {   REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI2 = 0;
     REST_TMS=0;
}
V { 
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
     REST_TMS=0;

}
V {  REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
    REST_TMS=1;

}
V { REST_TMS=0 ;
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;

}
Ann{"Load IR"}


I need to create a Awk or Sed script to search a certain pattern
First Search pattern is "Load DR" , Second Search pattern is REST_TMS=1
Third Search pattern is "REST_TMS=0" and Third Search pattern is REST_TMS=0
Means After searching "Load DR" , it would search 1 0 0 sequence for TMS and then insert NEW_TRAN string before the third TMS=0
Output File

Module1 (a dd ddd )
jdjd ikdnd kdndn didkdn;
jdjdjl kdkdk kdkd lkd;
Ann {"Load DR"}  ;
V { REST_TMS=1 ;
      REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
}
V {   REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI2 = 0;
     REST_TMS=0;
}
NEW_TRAN
V { REST_TMS=0 ;
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;

}
V { 
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
     REST_TMS=1;
}
jjd djdjdj djdj (ndhdn )
jdjdjd jdjd jdjd 
Ann( " Load IR"}
Ann ("Load DR 2"}
V { REST_TMS=1 ;
      REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
}
V {   REST_TDI = 0
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI2 = 0;
     REST_TMS=0;
}
NEW_TRAN 
V { 
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
     REST_TMS=0;

}
V {  REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;
    REST_TMS=1;

}
V { REST_TMS=0 ;
      REST_TDI = 1
      REST_TCK=1 ;
     REST_TDI = 0;

}
Ann{"Load IR"}


I have used below stated code to search a series of Search pattern
awk '/Load DR/{f=1}f&&/REST_TMS = 1;/f&&/REST_TMS"= 0/f&&/REST_TMS"= 0/{print "NEW_TRAN"}1' File1

It is printing NEW_TRAN everywhere where the REST_TMS=0
Please help me out

In your file1 example you show a sequence of 1 1 0 1 for  REST_TMS after ”Load DR“. According to your description this should not match.

TMS can have a sequence of 1 0 0 1 after Load DR but it should actually search for 1 0 0  sequence only and it should insert NEW_TRAN just before the third 0 TMS

I have edited the query once again

your sample output inserts NEW_TRAN before V before second REST_TMS=0, not before third

yes that is required it should search in a sequence for 1 0 0 for TMS and then insert NEW_TRAN before the second TMS = 0

If you have one file where this has to be done once, why not just use your text editor and be done with it?

Please [edit] your question to replace the word "pattern" with regexp or string plus full or partial, etc. so we can help you. Otherwise you're likely to end up with a solution that works for your sample input but fails at some point now or in future with false matches when run on your real data. See how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern. The current answers you have are making assumptions about your data and requirements that may not be true.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E '/Load DR/!b
       :a;N;/Load IR/!ba
       y/\n/\o00/;s/REST_TMS/\n/g
       s/(\n=1[^\n]*\n=0[^\n]*\o00)([^\n\o00]*\n=0)/\1\o00NEW_TRAN\o00\2/
       s/\n/REST_TMS/g;y/\o00/\n/
       s/\n(V \{[^}]*)(\nNEW_TRAN\n)/\2\1/' file

Focus on lines between lines containing Load DR and Load IR.
Replace all occurrences of newlines by nulls and all REST_TMSs by newlines.
Pattern match the required 1 0 0 following newlines and insert NEW_TRAN
before the last match.
Reinstate newlines and the text REST_TMS.
Fix up the inserted text to be before a line starting V {.
N.B. This assumes each stanza ends with Load IR and no nulls appear in the text.

An ameliorated version of the above solution:
sed -E '/Load DR/!b
        :a;N;/Load IR/!ba
        s/REST_TMS\s*=\s*/&\x00/g
        s/\x001[^\x00]*\x000[^\x00]*\x000/&\nNEW_TRAN/
        s/(\nV \{[^}]*)(\nNEW_TRAN)/\2\1/
        s/\x00//g' file


Solution in TXR:
We can see using Bash process substitution and diff that the command txr edit.txr data is making the right edit:
$ diff -u data <(txr edit.txr data)
--- data        2024-07-07 19:19:00.970060535 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/63  2024-07-07 19:38:28.246655220 -0700
@@ -12,6 +12,7 @@
      REST_TDI2 = 0;
      REST_TMS=0;
 }
+NEW_TRAN
 V { REST_TMS=0 ;
       REST_TDI = 1
       REST_TCK=1 ;

Code in edit.txr:
@(data top)
@(skip)
Ann {"Load DR"} ;
V { REST_TMS=@a ;
@(skip)
}
V {@nil
@(skip)
 REST_TMS=@b;
}
@(data inspoint)
V { REST_TMS=@c ;
@(do
   (put-lines (ldiff top inspoint))

   (if-match "1 0 0" `@a @b @c`
     (put-line "NEW_TRAN"))

   (put-lines inspoint))

In color:


Regarding

printing NEW_TRAN everywhere where the REST_TMS=0

Consider 2nd pattern i.e. this responsible for {print "NEW_TRAN"}
f&&/REST_TMS = 1;/f&&/REST_TMS"= 0/f&&/REST_TMS"= 0/

it does consist of 4 parts AND-ed (&&) together, namely
f
/REST_TMS = 1;/f
/REST_TMS"= 0/f
/REST_TMS"= 0/

observe that 2nd and 3rd are using concatenation, either /REST_TMS = 1;/ or /REST_TMS"= 0/ with variable f. Effect of concatenation with f equal 1 is either 01 or 11 and both are considered true, therefore above pattern is equivalent to writing
f&&/REST_TMS"= 0/


Here is a kind of cheater way to multiline manipulate sed, you may want to use SOH instead of + to get rid of the nl's:
tr '\n' '+' < data.txt > /tmp/temp.txt 

while read -r a; do  
 sed -i "s/\($a\)/\1\nNEW_TRANS/" /tmp/temp.txt
done < <(grep -Po '(Load DR)(.+?)(REST_TMS=1)(.+?)(REST_TMS=0)(.+?})' /tmp/temp.txt)

tr '+' '\n' < /tmp/temp.txt > data_fixed.txt

You first collapse the text by eliminating nl's replacing with a token.
Then use PCRE from grep to get the replace string, sed to replace the text with NEW_TRANS to follow and finally translate the tokens back to nl's.
